# #1054 - Unknown column 'e.ProjectID' in 'on clause'

Tags: mysql

I am getting error #1054 - Unknown column 'e.ProjectID' in 'on clause' with the following SQL

```
SELECT ProjectID
FROM Project as p
INNER JOIN (SELECT EquipID , EquipName , EquipTypeID , (EquipPrice*Quantity) As CstAmount     FROM Equipment) as e
ON p.ProjectID=e.ProjectID
```

Comment: add `ProjectID` inside the subquery.

Comment: Please formulate an actual question, related to a piece of code, which you also should post

Comment: actually you don't need subquery for this since you need only `ProjectID`.

Comment: thanks, i want to get all these entities from these tables,this problem message still occurs..How should i do.

Answer (score 0):

Your subquery doesn't have that column exposed to the outer query.

```
SELECT ProjectID
FROM   Project As p
 INNER
  JOIN (
        SELECT ProjectID
             , EquipID
             , EquipName
             , EquipTypeID
             , (EquipPrice*Quantity) As CstAmount
        FROM   Equipment
       ) As e
    ON p.ProjectID = e.ProjectID
```

However, if you're only wanting to return the ProjectID then I suggest you perform this query instead:

```
SELECT ProjectID
FROM   Project
WHERE  EXISTS (
         SELECT *
         FROM   Equipment
         WHERE  ProjectID = Project.ProjectID
       )
```

Comment: Why at all you need subquery? Looking at his query it looks simple inner join

Answer (score 0):

You dont need any subquery. Just join project table with equipment table as following

```
SELECT p.ProjectID,e.EquipID ,e.EquipName ,e.EquipTypeID ,e.EquipPrice* e.Quantity as CstAmount from Project P join Equipment e on  p.ProjectID=e.ProjectID
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do  this without subquery

```
 SELECT p.ProjectID ,e.EquipID , e.EquipName , e.EquipTypeID , (e.EquipPrice * e.Quantity) As CstAmount
 FROM Project as p
 INNER JOIN Equipment  as e
 ON p.ProjectID= e.ProjectID
```

Comment: you'll get an error because ProjectID exists in both tables. add prefix in the SELECT

Answer (score 0):

what are you trying to do? your query can be rewritten like the following but i doubt this is what you want

```
SELECT p.ProjectID
FROM Project as p
INNER JOIN Equipment as e
ON p.ProjectID = e.ProjectID
```

do you need to select your subquery's fields as well?